# How to create a list view the returns all the records related to a current user?

Tags: administration, lookup, list-view

**Question**

Assuming an object with a user lookup, how can I create a list view (standard, not VF) that returns all objects related to the current user?

**Background**

We've got a compliance object, and the person who fills it out is populate in a user lookup.  There is no owner since the object is master detailed to another object.  Is there anyway to get the same effect as the "My Records" list views but for a custom user lookup?  Seems like each user is going to have to create a list view on their own, but was curious if there were any non-coding solutions to making one that can work for everybody (like the "My Records" list views).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of a listview looks weird both in [listview documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listview.htm#filterScope) and in Force.com IDE (examples at the bottom of the linked page). It's not like there's a hidden filter that goes `OwnerId = User.Id`...

You could try making a numeric formula along the lines of `IF(User_Lookup__c =  $User.Id, 1, 0)` and then referencing it in your filters?

Comment: That's a wild idea about the formula field. I'll give it a try :) and report back

Comment: I'm not worthy!! That nailed it, genius idea!!

Comment: Another satisfied customer :)

Comment: Here's a blog post that addresses this as well: [http://youraveragesalesforceadmin.blogspot.ca/2011/06/tips-records-created-by-current-user.html](http://youraveragesalesforceadmin.blogspot.ca/2011/06/tips-records-created-by-current-user.html)