# What can I use instead of apex:repeat?

Tags: apex, class

I need to find the way to use something different than apex:repeat. to assign the 
value="{!thousandBlocks} var="block"  This is creating multiple tables and i don't want that.

Let me explain you, the class is requesting a large amount of data and i created a wrapper class. and for some reason the vf page is displaying many pageBlockTables and I just want to display just one. My guess is that the apex:repeat is causing this. So I was wondering if there is another apex control that I can use instead of 'repeat' to get the value="{!thousandBlocks} var="block"

I will appreciate any help

VF Page code:

```
       <apex:pageBlock >

          <apex:repeat value="{!thousandBlocks} var="block"   >

           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!block.zeroInventory}" var="p" id="mid">
           <apex:column value="{!p.Account__r.Name}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/>
           <apex:column value="{!p.Product_Name__c}"/>


           </apex:pageBlockTable>
          </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

class:

```
    public class dashBoardPOIssues {
 private limitWrapper[] thousandBlocks = new limitWrapper[]{};
 private final integer listLimit;  

 public dashBoardPOIssues(){

    //for zero inventory
    listLimit = 950;
 }

  //for zero inventory
  public limitWrapper[] getthousandBlocks()
{
thousandBlocks = new limitWrapper[]{};

integer counter = 0;
integer loopCount = 0;
NRProducts__c[] tmpcase = new NRProducts__c[]{};

for(NRProducts__c c:[SELECT id, Name, Account__r.Name, ASIN__c,CreatedDate,Product_Name__c,Virtual_Amz__c,Total_Inventory2__c,Days_of_Inventory__c,X24_Hr_Units__c,X7_Day_Units__c,X30_Day_Units__c   FROM NRProducts__c  WHERE  Total_Inventory2__c = 0  AND Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId()])
{
    if(counter < listLimit)
    {
        tmpcase.add(c);
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        loopCount++;
        thousandBlocks.add(new limitWrapper(tmpcase,loopCount));
        tmpcase = new NRProducts__c[]{};
        tmpcase.add(c);
        counter = 0;
    }            
  }

if(thousandBlocks.size() == 0)
{
    loopCount++;
    thousandBlocks.add(new limitWrapper(tmpcase,loopCount));
}

return thousandBlocks;
}

 public class limitWrapper
 {
  public NRProducts__c [] zeroinventory {get;set;}
  public integer blockNumber {get;set;}
  public limitWrapper(NRProducts__c[] accs, integer i)
{
    zeroinventory = accs;
    blockNumber = i;
}

}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?  I'm not really sure what you want.  Btw, you closed your repeat and then close it again later **<apex:repeat value="{!thousandBlocks} var="block"   />**

Comment: Let me explain you, the class is requesting a large amount of data and i created a wrapper class. and for some reason the vf page is displaying many pageBlockTables and I just want to display just one. My guess is that the apex:repeat is causing this. So I was wondering if there is another apex control that I can use instead of 'repeat' to get the value="{!thousandBlocks} var="block"

Comment: Well, by having ANY sort of repeat around a table will cause it to create multiple tables.  If you want to create only a single table, that has to be your outermost level.

Comment: dphil, I have another open question, could you please help me with that.

Comment: The question that we need to understand to answer your question is why do you need a list of NRProducts__c inside of a list of wrappers?

Comment: because I was getting an  error Collection size 1,156 exceeds maximum size of 1,000. Then I found this approach and I use it. I am very new in Salesforce, to be honest I don't know if this is correct. i tested it in production and for some users is working but they see multiple tables, for some others that have more time in the company(more record) I am getting another error Response size exceeded 15MB organization limit but opened another question for that. Here is the http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40686/response-size-exceeded-15mb-organization-limit

Comment: What is the business reason for needing two collections, what are the business requirements?

Comment: i don't understand your question, if are referring to wrapper class structure, I found this example online and I modified it

Comment: Also, why would you want to display more than 1000 rows on a page. This seems like a less than usable UI.

Comment: we are considering to create a workaround for that.. you are right there are too many records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered a similar question some time ago: [Add more than 1000 picklist values in visualforce page (controller 1000 list items limit)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/add-more-than-1000-picklist-values-in-visualforce-page-controller-1000-list-ite)

You should ask yourself how usable it'll be to display over 1000 records? This suggests it's going to be a dashboard component - that'd be pretty long one...

---

Your "proper" options:

1. If it's a readonly display of data then mark the `<apex:page readonly="true">` and the limit will go to 10K.
2. If it's acceptable for you to display some kind of pagination then you should read up on how to use [StandardSetController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) for example.
3. You could build a listview in that objects tab that meets the filter criteria (Use formula field like in [How to create a list view the returns all the records related to a current user?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11561/how-to-create-a-list-view-the-returns-all-the-records-related-to-a-current-user) to implement the filter on the `Buyer_lookup__c`). Once you have that you can simply throw the [`<apex:enhancedList>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) at the page, no apex code required, no unit tests to write...
4. If it's really to be a dashboard component - why not simply build a report?

---

Your "subprime" ;) option (because even if you'll manage to get it to work you'll hit limits like viewstate or the one you've quoted: "Response size exceeded 15MB") would be to create a `List<List<NRProducts__c>>` and have 2 nested `<apex:repeat>`s.

It could look similar to that (I have 36 Opportunities in my Developer Edition):

[image]

```
public class ListLimitWorkaround{
    public ListLimitWorkaround(){}

    public List<List<Opportunity>> getChunkedRecords(){
        Integer sizeLimit = 5;    // flip to 1000
        List<List<Opportunity>> opps = new List<List<Opportunity>>();

        List<Opportunity> temp = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity]){
            temp.add(o);
            if(temp.size() == sizeLimit){    // limit reached? Then add our current workaround list and spawn new one
                opps.add(temp);
                temp = new List<Opportunity>();
            }
        }
        // We've left the loop? We should check if there are any leftovers in 'temp' that still have to be added
        if(!temp.isEmpty()){
            opps.add(temp);
        }
        return opps;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="ListLimitWorkaround">

<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
    <ol>
        <apex:repeat value="{!chunkedRecords}" var="chunk">
            <apex:repeat value="{!chunk}" var="opp">
                <li>{!opp.Name}</li>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ol>
</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">
    <ol>
        <apex:repeat value="{!chunkedRecords}" var="chunk">
            <li><ol>
                <apex:repeat value="{!chunk}" var="opp">
                    <li>{!opp.Name}</li>
                </apex:repeat>
            </ol></li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ol>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Dear downvoter - how can I improve this post?

Comment: No probs :) I think anything but the #1 will solve your response size problem too.

Comment: Thank you very much... there are so many things i need to learn about the governor limits and some times it is so frustrating specially for my entry level experience. Do you know where can I find more examples about this type of list: List<List<NRProducts__c>> Thank you in advance!